# Metalog all logs are printed with [kernel]

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, syslog

I installed metalog my server and using C++ application to write logs.
Here is how I print to system logging

```
openlog(facility.c_str(), LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PERROR, LOG_LOCAL0);

syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s", stderr_msg.c_str());
```

All my logs are printed with the format:

```
<date> [kernel] <log text message>
```

for example

```
Dec 05 12:19:31 [kernel] this is an example of log
```

I want to change it that instead of [kernel], it will print the relevant module.
Or at least my application name, but not 'kernel'.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I started Metalog from another process, which pointed its stdout & stderr to /dev/kmsg, Hence the forked process of Metalog did the same. That caused the logs to look like they are from the kernel.